# Can I upload another apk if previous apk is rolled out to only 5% in Google Play

Tags: android

I have rolled out my apk to 5% on Google Play, now I suddenly found a critical bug which I fixed, is it possible to roll out another apk on top of older one without it increasing it any more further?

Comment: Change the version number and version code and upload a new apk.Your user will get the updated apk

Comment: Why do you under vote? Rather you can answer if you know!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to roll out another apk on top of older one without it
>   increasing it any more further?

Yes its possible.

You **need to increment the version number and version code** of your app (in the AndroidManifest.xml) and build a new apk and upload the same to Play Store.

The users who haven't received the previous update will directly get the new update and the users who have already got the previous update will get a new update on top of it.